# RestSharp dll in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to make Rest Call through C#, to do that I am using RestSharp dll.

I have created farm level solution and added webpart, then installed RestSharp through NuGet.

The issue I am facing is in following line:

`var client2 = new RestClient(webURL);`

The moment I add this line, I am getting 'does not have strong name' error.

```
Referenced assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.
```

Then I created a console application added same dll and tried, it worked.

Then I created a simple web application and then added same dll and tried, it worked.

It is only failing when I am trying through webpart.

I really appreciate if anyone can guide me or give me some tip to solve this issue.

Comment: which nuget pakage did you install. According to the github home page RestSharp is now signed https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Comment: @NadeemYousuf I installed RestSharp 105.0.0.0 from Nugut. 
   Strange thing is I installed same dll from Nugut into another application and it is working but the moment I add it in webpart solution, its giving this error.

Comment: SharePoint (webpart) dlls are deployed to GAC and hence need to be signed. You need to grab the Nuget package which has the RetSharp dll signed

Comment: Thanks @NadeemYousuf. I wasn't aware of signed version of RestSharp dll.
 Learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestSharp has a signed version on Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharpSigned/

```
Install-Package RestSharpSigned
```

I've used this in a Farm Solution and can confirm it works.